# network user isolation

Tags: networking, linux-networking

My question is for a network with a Linux iptables router gateway. How can it be possible to prevent inter-network traffic of those users. Think this case as a public network, IPs are distributed through linux gw and users are authenticated thru the gateway. We want to protect public users from public users. Network is not wireless and I can not use Wireless AP user isolation.

Actually I have a simple method. Subnet the network into /30 mask. Give minimum IP of each subnet to the gateay and ditribute those /30 IPs from the subnet. But this is pretty costly for such an aim.

I want to ask for other methods

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Private Vlans if your switch knows it. An other way is to put a L2 ACL wich limits the communication only to the MAC address of your router. Then your clients can only talk to the router and not between them. In both cases, your clients can be in the same big subnet.